# Is there a way to display the actual number instead of hex value in R.Java inside eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, decompiling, r.java-file

Hi I accidentally deleted my android project and I am trying to rebuild the app by de-compiling my apk file.
The thing now is the generated class files have all the resource values shown in numbers(eg:2130837504 instead of R.drawable.ic_launcher). So to make it more readable, I need to find the actual resource and remap these values. But in the R.java all the values are displayed in Hexadecimal format which makes it hard when you have lot of resources.
I could still find the value if I hover it on the name of the resource, but this process looks more tedious when there is lot of resources in the project.

So is there a way to make eclipse display the actual value instead of hex value, so that it will make my work little easier.

[image]

So I want eclipse to display as
"public static final int ic_launcher=2130837504;"

instead of
"public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;"

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do that, since it's not Eclipse, but Android (ADT) which creates the `R.java` and puts the resource in hex number.

Comment: @AndrewT. I too made research on this and this is what I thought...
But is there any other way to do that in eclipse?
Cos its able to display the actual value on hovering, right???
Cant it be made to always show this value against hex or something that's readable???

Comment: I have no idea... I'm sorry I can't help further than this. Hopefully someone later has solution for this.

Comment: @AndrewT. Anways Thanks for replying:)
Keep looking this, may be we will learn a new solution later:( , Hopefully:)